# how to use request animation frame in a code which follows the following pattern?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, bezier, requestanimationframe

I have been around this problem for days now.I have written my code in constructor pattern for the first time.I want to extend the height of 10 bezier lines in transition.I have tried kineticjs(i failed),tried Setinterval(creates jerk in animation).So I finally resorted to requestAnimationFrame.But because of this constructor pattern,I am totally confused where to include it and what changes are to be made.

This is what I have done so far---[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/UmSss/)

So basically I will be extending my endY and cpY1 and cpy2 in transition.Onmouseover of canvas the height of all bezier lines must increase in transition giving it an animation like feel.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//for entire code please have a look at the fiddle.this is just 10% of my code
//for simplification purpose,you can use 3 instances instead of 9!!!
    (function() {
        hair = function() {
            return this;
        };


    hair.prototype={

     draw_hair:function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){

            var sx  =136+a;//start position of curve.used in moveTo(sx,sy)
            var sy  =235+b;
            var cp1x=136+c;//control point 1
            var cp1y=222+d;
            var cp2x=136+e;//control point 2
            var cp2y=222+f;
            var endx=136+g;//end points
            var endy=210+h;

         var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
         var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         context.strokeStyle="grey";
         context.lineWidth="8";
         context.beginPath();
         context.moveTo(sx,sy);
         context.bezierCurveTo(cp1x,cp1y,cp2x,cp2y,endx,endy);
         context.lineCap = 'round';
         context.stroke();
    }
};
})();
```

Comment: I took your code and created a Hair "class" version complete with a constructor.  You supply this class with the number of hairs you need and it draws/redraws all hairs as needed as a group.  I did this to improve performance because the mousemove handler will only have to respond to 1 group instead of 9 individual objects.  I also added a method on the class that causes the hair to grow.  As we discussed, this is done by raising the "Y" coordinate of control points and the endpoint. Good luck with your project. :)

Comment: @markE:the moment i go over the grown hairs,they become short again which is not desired...but thats ok...I will take on from here
thanks mark!!!seriously...but small question apart from coding,What keeps you going at the age of 56!!!#respect

Comment: I'm happiest when I learn something new every day.  So far, life has supplied more than enough interesting things to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer you wanted about growing hair.

This also has the info you wanted about how to create a hair "object".

Code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8K825/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // the Hair "object"
    // Hair is a containing object that hosts a user-specified # of hairs
    var Hair = (function () {

        // constructor
        function Hair(x,y,width,height,haircount) {

            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            this.width=width;
            this.height=height;
            this.right=this.x+this.width;
            this.bottom=this.y+this.height;
            this.hairCount=haircount;
            this.startX=x+20;
            this.startY=y+height-3;  //235;
            this.hairHeight=25;
            this.hairGrowth=0;
            this.lastEndX=[];

            for(var i=0;i<haircount;i++){
                this.lastEndX[i]= x+20+(i*15);
            }

        }
        // grows the hair
        // works by changing the Y value of the end & control points
        Hair.prototype.grow = function(increment){
            this.hairGrowth+=increment;
            return(this.hairGrowth);
        }
        // draw all the hairs
        Hair.prototype.draw = function(mouseX){

            // clear this object's space on the canvas
            // and set its styles
            ctx.clearRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle="grey";
            ctx.lineWidth=7;
            ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            ctx.beginPath();

            for(var i=0;i<this.hairCount;i++){

                // straight hair 
                var sx=cp1x=cp2x= this.startX+(i*15);
                var sy= this.startY;
                var cp1y = cp2y = (this.startY-(this.hairHeight+this.hairGrowth)/2);
                var endy = this.startY-this.hairHeight-this.hairGrowth;
                var endx = this.lastEndX[i];

                // create bend, if any
                if(Math.abs(mouseX-sx)<=10){ 
                    endx = sx+(mouseX-sx)*1.1;
                    this.lastEndX[i]=endx;
                };

                // draw this curve
                ctx.moveTo(sx,sy);
                ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x,cp1y,cp2x,cp2y,endx,endy);

            }
            // stroke
            ctx.stroke();
            // temp outline
            ctx.lineWidth=1;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        //
        return Hair;
    })();


    var direction=1;
    var fps = 3;
    function animate() {
        setTimeout(function() {

            // change hair length
            var hairLength=hair.grow(direction);
            if(hairLength<1 || hairLength>10){ direction=(-direction); }

            // draw
            hair.draw();

            // request next frame
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        }, 1000 / fps);
    }


    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#movelog").html("Move: "+ mouseX + " / " + mouseY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(mouseX>=hair.x && mouseX<=hair.right && mouseY>=hair.y && mouseY<=hair.bottom){
          hair.draw(mouseX);
      }
    }

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

    $("#grow").click(function(e){ animate(); });

    // create a new patch of hair 
    var hair=new Hair(25,50,150,50,8);
    hair.draw(225);


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="movelog">Move</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas><br>
    <button id="grow">Grow Hair</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Added: explanation of “Class” and instantiating an object from a class ]**

`var Hair=(function(){ …;  return Hair; })()` creates a Hair “class”.

`var hair = new Hair(…)` creates an actual, usable Hair “object”.

Think of the Hair-class as a template (or blueprint or cookie-cutter).  All the code inside Hair-class only defines the properties and methods of the class.  You don’t actually call any of the code in the Hair class.  You just use it as a template to create actual hair objects.

You can use the Hair class to create as many actual hair objects as you need—it’s reusable.  The act of creating a hair object is known as “instantiating the Hair-class”.

BTW, javascript does not actually have classes, so this is just a pseudo-class.   But that’s a whole other explanation!

*You ask: What’s the use of direction=0.25?*

The direction variable is used to incrementally increase the height of hair when hair is “growing” during animation.  The .25 tells the control/end points of the hair to go up by .25 pixels per animation frame.

*You ask: What’s the significance of callback function and that settimeout?*

`setTimeout` is wrapping `requestAnimationFrame` so that the animation occurs at a fixed frame-per-second.

RequestAnimationFrame (RAF) does a great job of optimizing performance, but you can’t control the frames-per-second with RAF alone. If you wrap RAF inside setTimeout, you can control the frames-per-second.  For example, setTimeout(anyFunction,1000/fps) will trigger anyFunction about 3 times a second when fps==3. See this nice article on RAF+setTimeout: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

As you discovered, RAF without setTimeout will still work, but RAF will try to grow your hair as quickly as possible, rather than with a fps interval.

Comment: var hair=new Hair(25,50,150,50,8);
now i think this is the instance that you have created.but i am confused what is referencing what i.e Hair is the outer object as well as the function name
and whats the use of direction=0.25?

Comment: and whats the significance of callback function and that settimeout?i commented out the code and executed,still it was running fine in my chrome browser.

Comment: See my appended answer to your questions. :)

Comment: new Hair(25,50,150,50,8) ----- 
    
what is hair in this...function or class???-------
the reason why I am asking is you are passing parameters to hair.If you see my previous example,you will notice this thing:-------

var hair(aka object)=new Hair(aka class);
hair.draw_hair(para1,para2)

Comment: Capital "H" Hair == class (the template).  Lowercase "h" hair == object (the usable hair).

Comment: but both class and hair are Hair in the code.So fuction Hair is a method?and its ok if classname and methd name matches???

Comment: Yes, perfectly ok.  Class [ var Hair=function() ] contains a contructor method [function Hair].  In languages that support true classes, it’s often the case that the constructor has the same name as the class.  This works in javascript because functions may contain functions.  In this case Class Hair contains constructor Hair.

Comment: :bad day at the office.They completely rejected what I showed to them.They find it rigid and are expecting some smoothness!!!
And articulated some new ideas.Like the hair should behave more naturally,the closest anology that I can give you is they want some wavy like flow.The way grass flows.
I tried to give some delay,but for no use its jerking!!totally screwed man
http://cssdeck.com/labs/4ksohwya
This link can help(complicated code i must say!!!)
Is it possible to give a wavy like feel on mousemove?

Comment: :any ideas regarding this or any link that has some vital info relating to my project?

Comment: Your current hair is a simple arc (a 1-way curve).  To be "wavy" you need a double-curve in your Bezier.  To do that you simply need to move your control points away from the X-axis. I suggest you build an experimental canvas with just 1 cubic Bezier curve and play with that curve until you understand how the control+end points affect the curve. That way you can adjust the control+end points to create wavy hair.  The "jerkiness" will almost fix itself after you understand the control points because you will have much finer control over the movement of the hair. Experiment+Understand=Success !!

Comment: :I have done this in the past and do understand the nature of bezier curve.But when it comes to animation like  
cssdeck.com/labs/4ksohwya 
i am rather not sure what to do?animation is sort back and forth if you see it carefully and that on mousemove is even more tough..

Comment: No...Not tough--when truly understood it's easy!  Experiment+Understand == Success.  Take their code and break it down to just 1 grass. Play!  Build a 1 Hair playground on canvas. Play!  When you **truly understand the nature of the cubic Bezier curve** and its control+end points, your task becomes easy.  Really!   ;)   But, without understanding the curve, you are throwing darts in a dark room.  With understanding, bending the curve based on mouse movement is simple as moving your own hair with hand).  So...don't copy cssdeck.com (it is good code). Instead Experiment with it + Understand !!

Comment: :the time parameter is difficult to understand.And based on this parameter they have used sin and cos which determines the movements?can you assist me on this??and what is that lerp function doing in there exactly??This code is CULT

Comment: Their time variable is literally clock time (a timer).  Their sin/cos are used so that the top endpoint of their curve moves in an arc rather than a horizontal line (more natural: as things with a fixed base sway, they get taller when they are most vertical and slightly shorter as they dip left/right).  Lerp is short for linear-interpolation, meaning tracking a point as it moves linearly. Their lerp is used to change colors across time (not relevant to their grass code).

Comment: :I went through several websites for tracking the nature of Sine and cos,But its quite a task to do it in a way that they have done!!!I have literally played quite a time now.But I am still vague about how time is being used and what is causing the smooth motion. Can you give a small module of it on a simple straight hair??

Comment: ::Assist me with this,One final time.grass like animation even on a single hair will do.PLz,just once.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171010/grass-like-smoothing-animation-on-beziercurve

Comment: Can do!  :)  ...see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171010/grass-like-smoothing-animation-on-beziercurve/17325855#17325855