# Efficient way to animate grass in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have been playing around with the capabilities of the 2d context of the canvas element to try to create relatively realistic 3d scenes and am currently trying to create a plain of 3d 'ish' grass as per fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PlacidCow/j6h7sajz/

My question is, what is the most efficient way to animate the grass to take in the effects of wind/physics etc?

Currently I've just drawn to screen - I have tried storing the dimensions of each blade in a large array which ofc then takes ages to loop through to animate (hence is laggy and pointless). Is there an efficient way to draw per blade? Or would people recommend animating per block (but then how to fix as clearing a patch will mess up blades in front)? repeating blades so they batch animate?

Have looked online (maybe I lack googling skills...) but I either find nothing, cagey webgl demos or examples for C etc but this use shaders which aren't available for 2d canvas.

```
c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var v = {
    w: c.clientWidth,
    h: c.clientHeight
};
c.width = v.w;
c.height = v.h;

var base = {
    c: [
        [-1, -1, 0],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [1, -1, -1],
        [1, -1, 0]
    ],
    f: 'brown',
    d: -3
};

draw(base.c, base.f, base.d);

for (var j=1; j<120; j++) {
    for (var k=1; k<200; k++) {
        var z = -1 + 2*j/199;
        var x = -1 + (2*Math.random())/1.01;
        var y = 0.06+Math.random()*0.04;
        var fl = Math.pow(-1, (Math.random()*1000)|0) * Math.random()/20;
        var blade = {
c: [
    [x, -1, z-Math.random()/1000],
    [x+0.002+fl, -1+y, z-Math.random()/1000],
    [x+0.007+fl, -1+y, z-Math.random()/1000],
    [x+0.02, -1, z-Math.random()/1000]
],
f: 'green',
d: 2
        };
        draw(blade.c, blade.f, blade.d);
    }
}

function draw(cds, fill, d) {
    var v = {
        w: c.clientWidth,
        h: c.clientHeight
    };

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(((cds[0][0] * (1 / (1 - cds[0][2])) + 1) * v.w / 2)|0, ((v.h - (cds[0][1] + 1) * v.h / 2) * (1 / (1 - cds[0][2])))|0);

    for (var i = 1; i < cds.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(((cds[i][0] * (1 / (1 - cds[i][2])) + 1) * v.w / 2)|0, ((v.h - (cds[i][1] + 1) * v.h / 2) * (1 / (1 - cds[i][2])))|0);
}
        ctx.lineTo(((cds[0][0] * (1 / (1 - cds[0][2])) + 1) * v.w / 2)|0, ((v.h - (cds[0][1]+1) * v.h / 2) * (1 / (1 - cds[0][2])))|0);

    if (Math.abs(d) == 1) {
        grd = ctx.createLinearGradient((200-200*d/Math.abs(d))/2, 0, (200+200*d/Math.abs(d))/2,0);
    } else if (Math.abs(d) == 2) {
        grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,((v.h - (cds[1][1] + 1) * v.h / 2) * (1 / (1 - cds[1][2])))|0,0,((v.h - (cds[0][1] + 1) * v.h / 2) * (1 / (1 - cds[0][2])))|0+v.h/100);
    } else if (Math.abs(d) == 3) {
        grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,(200-200*d/Math.abs(d))/2, 0, (200+200*d/Math.abs(d))/2);
    }
    grd.addColorStop(0, fill);
    grd.addColorStop(1, '#000');

    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Are one of these the effect you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171010/grass-like-smoothing-animation-on-beziercurve/17325855#17325855

Comment: I have already read that post and there are some neat ways to change the blades (will read everything again in case I missed an answer) - what I'm currently wondering is an efficient way to potentially affect all (on the fiddle 200x200=40000) blades at once due to wind say - or at least give a fooling impression

Comment: Most efficient way on the 2d canvas is probably to generate the image frames for each blade of grass and play through them. You can generate multiple sets and use different starting point to create the illusion that they are all unique.

Comment: Actually since you need 40,000 blades one image per blade wouldnt be fast enough (canvas can do about 10-15k image draws at 30FPS) so you need to create images representing multiple blades.

Comment: For efficiency, if your grass is 200px wide, then create a second 300x5 canvas (in memory canvas only). Then create many vertical rows of grass by drawing that second canvas repeatedly to the visible canvas with a random X-offset per row.

Comment: All sounds sensible, I'm sure some method of pre-rendering will definitely be the answer, but I'm struggling to picture how is best to set it up given that my hope was I would be able to implement both x-direction and z-direction movement to the blades (see fiddle demo with rather artificial turbulent wind: http://jsfiddle.net/PlacidCow/j6h7sajz/2/) If I store rows of blades from back to the front, I guess I can use canvas transforms (probs skew) to give the x-dir movement effect, but don't see how could get the z-dir... maybe a scale would do it...

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to pre generate all shapes that are possible for each blades of grass. I am not familiar with the math behind bending grass but lets assume every shape of grass can be described by 2 variables: bentX and bentZ. So I would break down the drawing process into 2: generate image frames for grass and rendering.

Pseudo code for frame generation:

```
var frames = [];
for (var i = min possible of bentX, l = max possible of bentX; i<=l; i += precision for bentX)
    for (var j = ... bentZ .... )
         frames[i][j] = image of grass at (i,j);
```

Then for rendering:

```
for each grassObj:
    bentX, bentZ = mathCalcs(grassObj);
    bentX, bentZ = clampToValidValue(bendX, bentZ); 
    frames[bendX][bentZ].draw();
```